# Twilio APIs still showing trial account message despite the account upgrade

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am working on Twilio APIs and everything is working fine with trail account. Now , I upgraded default project which is **My first Twilio project Dashboard** and sending message but this time i am getting below error message

> Unable to create record: The number is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.

Anybody, please help what i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: you have to purchase one number, which is used as from number. with using that number you can send.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra ahan, okay let me buy number.